# how to add qr code to google model viewer?

Tags: 3d, augmented-reality, qr-code, barcode, model-viewer

I need to show QR code when the website is in desktop mode, so the user can scan the qr code and access the 3d model in his space

A QR code that can show ar model with the help of google model viewer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.